Scheduled Refresh MView fails with ORA-12008
I have a MView that is refreshed daily using DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MVIEW_NAME', atomic_refresh=>TRUE); The refresh is launched by a scheduled job.
This MView is based on a standard view in which I replaced a dblink source with a table(with the same structure).
The issue is that after this replacement, the refresh is failing with ORA-12008:
MV 'MVIEW_NAME' was not refreshed successfully.
CRDWH(3):Number of MV refresh failures: 1.
CRDWH(3):Encountered error ORA-12008.
No other details are logged at db level.
If I run manually the MView statement or begin DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MVIEW_NAME', atomic_refresh=>TRUE); end; command it works successfully.
Have you any idea of how should I resolve this?
Oracle DB version: 19.23.0.0.0
Best regards,
D
I run manually the MView statement or begin DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MVIEW_NAME', atomic_refresh=>TRUE); end; command it works successfully.
I've checked db logs and there are no other errors related to this view.

My Oracle Support in document 2738707.1 says that this is caused by bug. Solution is to apply a patch.
Ask your DBA to read that document for more details (we aren't allowed to share details in public).
